# Union of 2 pairs columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let's say I have a table in the format

```
a b c d 
1 v 3 x
2 w 4 y
3 x 5 z
4 y 1 v
```

with columns a,b,c, and d. I want a union of columns a and c while keeping column pair a+b and c+d locked. I want the output to be

```
col1 col2
1       v
2       w
3       x
4       y
5       z
```

I know how to use UNION ALL to join two columns, but how do I join two columns while each of these 2 columns are paired with another column each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `UNION` and not `UNION ALL` to filter duplicate pairs :

```
SELECT a,b FROM YourTable 
UNION
SELECT c,d FROM YourTable
```

Comment: I see, but how does mysql know (or how do i specify) to Union according to columns a and c and not b and d?

Comment: @piface314 I'm not sure I understand the question. This query should return your expected result.